# Have issues in getting probability values using SVM in R

Tags: r, statistics, classification, svm, probability

I am having a data set which has 28 attributes. The response variable is binary (0 & 1). I tried using SVM with "Probability=T" while running it. But I still could not get the probability values from the result.

Here is my training data set (last attribute is my response variable):

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   73630 obs. of  29 variables:
 $ EMOTION_INDICATOR: num  -2 -0.625 0.9 0 1.625 ...
 $ CLUSTER          : Factor w/ 8 levels "","cluster0",..: 4 7 5 1 1 3 8 6 7 1 ...
 $ GENDER           : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Female","Male": 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ AGE              : num  36 37 70 NA NA ...
 $ REGION           : Factor w/ 6 levels "","'Northern Ireland'",..: 5 6 5 1 1 6 4 4 6 1 ...
 $ WORKING          : Factor w/ 14 levels "","A","B","C",..: 4 14 8 1 1 6 4 3 4 1 ...
 $ MUSIC            : Factor w/ 7 levels "","A","B","C",..: 5 7 6 1 1 4 5 2 5 1 ...
 $ LIST_OWN         : num  1 1 6 NA NA ...
 $ LIST_BACK        : num  1 3 2 NA NA 0.5 2 0.5 6 NA ...
 $ Q1               : num  10 51 35 NA NA 29 51 25 69 NA ...
 $ Q2               : num  53 51 36 NA NA 7 49 25 71 NA ...
 $ Q3               : num  12 70 37 NA NA 26 51 23 70 NA ...
 $ Q4               : num  11 31 36 NA NA 2 50 24 7 NA ...
 $ Q5               : num  12 6 37 NA NA 51 73 22 10 NA ...
 $ Q6               : num  12 6 9 NA NA 51 47 22 68 NA ...
 $ Q7               : num  76 5 36 NA NA 29 50 30 11 NA ...
 $ Q8               : num  76 24 13 NA NA 72 52 10 10 NA ...
 $ Q9               : num  51 7 70 NA NA 12 36 48 53 NA ...
 $ Q10              : num  53 70 69 NA NA 9 91 18 75 NA ...
 $ Q11              : num  76 89 65 NA NA 53 53 18 86 NA ...
 $ Q12              : num  76 91 63 NA NA 5 52 16 89 NA ...
 $ Q13              : num  52 50 6 NA NA 51 77 17 99 NA ...
 $ Q14              : num  75 73 62 NA NA 70 78 21 100 NA ...
 $ Q15              : num  11 72 31 NA NA 33 48 19 67 NA ...
 $ Q16              : num  12 47.7 24.3 NA NA ...
 $ Q17              : num  71 74 51 NA NA 51 52 27 98 NA ...
 $ Q18              : num  23.6 52 31 NA NA ...
 $ Q19              : num  22.5 52 32 NA NA ...
 $ AVERAGE_RATING   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

My test set looks similar too. It has 24544 obs. with 29 variables.

This is the code that I used for SVM:

```
fitSVM <- svm(AVERAGE_RATING ~., data=train, na.action = na.omit,probability=T)
predSVM <- predict(fitSVM,test[!rowSums(is.na(test)),],type="probability")
table(predSVM,test$AVERAGE_RATING[!rowSums(is.na(test))],useNA="no")
predSVM    0    1
      0 8091 1523
      1 3259 9865
```

I get proper output, but without probability values:

```
attr(predSVM,"probabilities")
NULL
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `predict` with:

```
predSVM <- predict(fitSVM,test[!rowSums(is.na(test)),], probability=T)
```

See `? predict.svm`